# How to get full URL from compressed URL in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a compressed URL of place holder site (http://placehold.it/600/24f355). 
how can I get full URL (https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=56&bg=24f355&txt=600%C3%97600&w=600&h=600) from the compressed URL in Android?

I tried the following but I get same URL what I give.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String shortURL = "http://placehold.it/600/24f355";

System.out.println("Short URL: " + shortURL);
URLConnection urlConn = connectURL(shortURL);
urlConn.getHeaderFields();
System.out.println("Original URL: " + urlConn.getURL());
}

static URLConnection connectURL(String strURL) {
    URLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        URL inputURL = new URL(strURL);
        conn = inputURL.openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Please input a valid URL");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to the URL");
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: The same code works for me. Try HttpURLConnection in place of URLConnection.

Comment: @gRaWEty - The OP's code does not work for me either. I get the same `URL` again.

Comment: You need to follow the redirects till you are getting 3xx response codes. So you can recursively call the same method till you get 200,201,202

Comment: Check my answer. That works for me. @TDG

Comment: @gRaWEty - The code from your answer works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/), you need to check the response code (`conn.getResponseCode()`), and if it is a 3xx (= redirection), you can get the new URL from the "Location" header field.

```
String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL address=new URL("your short URL");


    //Connect & check for the location field
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.connect();
        String expandedURL = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        if(expandedURL != null) {
            URL expanded = new URL(expandedURL);
            address= expanded;
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Problem while expanding {}"+ address+ e);
    } finally {
        if(connection != null) {
            System.out.println(connection.getInputStream());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Original URL"+address);
}
```